# Modelsim "Failed to map the library" error

Tags: vhdl, modelsim

I have written this simple code. But when i try to simulate it using Modelsim, it shows the an error saying library cannot be mapped. How do i sort it?

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity p1 is
    Port ( a : in  STD_LOGIC;
           b : in  STD_LOGIC;
           c : out  STD_LOGIC);
end p1;

architecture Behavioral of p1 is

begin

c <= a or b;

end Behavioral;
```

This is the error:

> ERROR: Failed to map the library

Comment: please remove the xilinx tag. And in what library are you trying to compile the file? Have you created that library and a logical mapping to it?

Answer (score 0):

probably you changed directory, and library `work` is not created there, although a mapping exists in your modelsim.ini.

Type in transcript:

```
vlib work
```

To create the library `work`.

edit: if the mapping is also missing (i.e. the above solution does not solve this) add the following command:

```
vmap work work
```

P.s. Stupid thing is: modelsim should not default to a library named "work", as "work" is a reserved keyword (meaning 'the current library'). But ignore that, as that has been an issue/bug for tens of years now...